# How to use Arrow function for returning anonymous function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have following code in ECMA5 and I'm trying to replace anonymous function to arrow function.
How can I achieve this? Can I replace both or one or none function with Arrow function?

```
var counterSetup = function () {
      var counter = 0;
      return function () {
        counter += 1;
        console.log('Increment counter value : ' + counter);
        return counter;
     };
};
var counter = counterSetup();
counter();
```

Comment: The above works fine using or not using an arrow function. I don't see the benefit of using an arrow function here. Why do you need an arrow function?

Comment: "*I'm not able to do it by directly replacing*" - yes you should be. Please show us what you've tried, and what error you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
var counter = () => {
  var counter = 0;
  return () => {
    counter += 1;
    console.log('Increment counter value : ' + counter);
    return counter;
  }
}();
alert(counter());
alert(counter());
alert(counter());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a return statement like this:

```
return function() {
    // statement 1 
    // statement 2
    return result;
}
```

The equivalent arrow function would look like this:

```
return () => {
    // statement 1 
    // statement 2
    return result;
}
```

Not that because of the multiple statements you need

- an explicit return statement
- opening / closing braces `{}`